# Why, when adding a const modifier to a fundamental type, can it be created as a constexpr, but not for a user-defined type?

Tags: c++

When a constant fundamental type is created, it can be evaluated by the compiler as a constexpr expression. This is clearly visible when using the is_constant_evaluated() function. While user-defined types cannot evolve into a constexpr expression, even if it is trivial, pod and standard_layout.

Is it possible to define a custom type so that when using a constant variable, it is evaluated at compile time?

Here is a short code that shows the difference

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    int x;
    
    constexpr Foo(int n) noexcept : x(n) {};
    
    constexpr operator int() const noexcept { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    using type = Foo; //or int
    
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    
              auto a1 = type(std::is_constant_evaluated() ? 0 : b);//b,b int/Foo
    const     auto a2 = type(std::is_constant_evaluated() ? 0 : b);//0,b int/Foo
    constexpr auto a3 = type(std::is_constant_evaluated() ? 0 : b);//0,0 int/Foo
          
    cout << (int)a1 << ' '  << (int)a2 << ' ' << (int)a3;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not any fundamental types, it's just integral and enumeration types. This stems from making `const int` usable as an array size etc. back when there was no `constexpr` keyword yet.